# Syncing data between room sqlite and server

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-room, android-livedata, android-viewmodel

I'm stuck in between development of my "notes" app. I am using Andoid liveData + ViewModel + Room. My concern is whenever I add/update/delete any note from my Local sqlite DB, how to sync this change with the DB in my server. Any help regarding the flow will be apppreciated.

Comment: Why you need custom sqlite db if you use Room? For the rest of you question, there are large number of option to do that. You can use Volley, OkHttp3 or retrofit2 for network communication. search those libraries in google.

Comment: @Maksim, I'm using volley in my other projects too. But my concern is whether the service call should be made from the repository? What architecture should i follow to sync data in my local with server?